# Confidence interval for probability distribution in Python

Tags: python, statistics, confidence-interval

I want to calculate the confidence interval for a distribution (Pearson 3), I'm using scipy.stats. With stats.pearson3.interval I only have the confidence interval for the mean, but I need the confidence interval for all my data. So, I need an image like this:

[image]

I know in matlab this is easy, using a cdf function, but I didn't find anything like this in Python.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to fit a Pearson 3 cdf to your data and you want the confidence band for the fit?